# Current user location for iOS 8 - App won't launch

Tags: ios, core-location, currentlocation

I have been working on a simple app to get the users current location using the Core Location framework from Apple in Xcode and when i run the app i get an error. Can someone please tell me what i did wrong thank you in advance. I have this code here in the Implementation file.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController { CLLocationManager *locationManager;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically   from   a nib.

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {

locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    _longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",     currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}
}





@end
```

This is the Header file...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController  : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender;

@end
```

And this is the output of the crash...

```
2016-01-11 11:53:58.346 current location practice[1367:32081] ***     Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<ViewController 0x7ff240d80cb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
 this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key getCurrentLocation.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee29f45   __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e8a3deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee29b89 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   Foundation                          0x000000010e470a6b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
4   UIKit                               0x000000010f36104c -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
5   UIKit                               0x000000010f58ea71 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed6aa80 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
7   UIKit                               0x000000010f58d454 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
8   UIKit                               0x000000010f367c16 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
9   UIKit                               0x000000010f368542 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
10  UIKit                               0x000000010f3688a0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
11  UIKit                               0x000000010f369013 -[UIViewController view] + 27
12  UIKit                               0x000000010f24251c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
13  UIKit                               0x000000010f242c05 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
14  UIKit                               0x000000010f2544a5 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
15  UIKit                               0x000000010f1ce396 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
16  UIKit                               0x000000010f1d49c3 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1750
17  UIKit                               0x000000010f1d1ba3 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011219f784 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011219faf2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed56011 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed4bf3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed4b3f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed4ae08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
24  UIKit                               0x000000010f1d14f5 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
25  UIKit                               0x000000010f1d630d UIApplicationMain + 171
26  current location practice           0x000000010e3224bf main + 111
27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111d5892d start + 1
)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type     NSException
(lldb)
```

Can someone please tell me what i did wrong and what i can do to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: most likely you have configured something wrong in Interface builder. Check that your xib/storyboard points to the correct class and then check all your IBOutlets and IBActions

Answer (score 0):

As per below errors:

```
6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed6aa80 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
7   UIKit                               0x000000010f58d454 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
```

It seems, your IBAction is not bounded with `getCurrentLocation` method, or is added wrongly.

Comment: checkout this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It's right at the top of the error message:

```
2016-01-11 11:53:58.346 current location practice[1367:32081] ***     Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<ViewController 0x7ff240d80cb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key getCurrentLocation.'
```

It's telling you that you're trying to use a key called `getCurrentLocation` on your class `ViewController`, but the class doesn't have that key. Most likely this means something's wrong with your storyboard. One scenario that would cause this would be connecting a button to an action named `getCurrentLocation`, but then deleting that method and not updating the storyboard.